# web based FTP help needed

Tags: php, web-applications, open-source, ftp

I am looking for a web based FTP client for our clients that is password protected, they can upload & download files.

Each client must have a user/pass to login into their folders.

Any reccomendation of open source would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few:

http://freshmeat.net/projects/asukphpftp/

http://oliver.sourceforge.net/

http://www.net2ftp.com/

http://code.google.com/p/f-it/

Comment: 2nd link have nothing.

Answer (score 1):

www.net2ftp.com

Answer (score 0):

[PHPanywhere.net](http://phpanywhere.net) is an online FTP client and PHP editor.